# Python 3 way partitioning (Quicksort)

Tags: python, quicksort, partitioning

I am trying to write a python code for the 3 way partition, however I get an indexing error. I tried to fix it but do not seem to succeed. In my code I pick the first entry to be the pivot and then scan from left and from right, swapping the values if necessary. If any entry is equal to pivot I either move it to the beginning or to the end(where I get an error) of a.

This is my code

```
def partition(a, start, end):
    left=start+1
    right=end
    p=start+1
    q=end
    pivot=a[start]
    while True:
        while a[left]<pivot:
            left+=1
        while a[right]>pivot:
            right-=1
            if right==start+1:
                break
        if left>=right:
            break
        swap(a[left], a[right])
        if a[left]==pivot:
            swap(a[p],a[left])
            p+=1
        if a[right]==pivot:
            swap(a[right], a[q])
            q-=1
    swap(a[right], a[start])
    k=end
    while k>=q+1:
        swap(a[left+1], a[k]) 
        k-=1
        left+=1
    k=1
    while k<p:
        swap(a[k], a[right+1])
        k+=1
        right-=1
```

and I define swap as:

```
def swap(a, b):
    temp=a
    a=b
    b=temp
```

when I try to run this function I get an error in line 21, that index out of range. Any suggestions on what is wrong here?

Comment: Your `swap` function does nothing. Python does not pass variables by reference.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it and now it seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments on the question, the `swap()` function in your code doesn't do anything.  In Python, names are just labels attached to objects.  If you assign to a name, you just attach a label to an object.  When you pass an object to a function, the object is passed, not the names assigned to it.  Assignments inside a function only create local names for an object, but don't have any visible effect outside the function.

You can modify the *objects* passed into a function, though.  The following implementation of `swap()` would work:

```
def swap(a, i, j):
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
```

It modifies the list passed in as `a`.